# No such element: Unable to locate element error (selenium and python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
     
     
driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://www.maxfm.com.tr/ ") #radio website
sleep(2)
     
     
          
print("waiting...")
element=driver.find_element_by_id('livePlayer').click()
   
sleep(7)  
driver.find_element_by_class_name("player clearfix").click()
sleep(7)
```

Hello,
I want to start live radio automatically from the above website. I can open the live player pop-up window but I can't access the play button. I couldn't figure it out. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, after clicking on `livePlayer` button a new window is opened.
So, you have to switch to a new window in order to click the `player clearfix` button.
So, please try the following:

```
print("waiting...")
element=driver.find_element_by_id('livePlayer').click()

sleep(1)  
new_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("player clearfix").click()
```

In order to get back to the first, main window you will have to do the folowing:

```
first_window = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(first_window)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `sleep()` because Selenium's next function is only called when website is fully loaded:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\webcontrol\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.maxfm.com.tr/")

button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='livePlayer']")[0]
button.click()

new_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(new_window)

play = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='play']")[0]
play.click()
```

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='play']")[0]` will match all `a` elements for having `id='play'`. Play button is an `a` element and its id is `"play"`.

Comment: So, now you actually copied my answer but with some unnecessary changes? Okay :)